# Сравнение двух элементов одного массива в php

Tags: php, sql, массивы

Добрый день, возникла проблема со сравнением двух элементов одного массива.
Массив берётся из базы. Требуется сравнить два поля title и original_title и, если они равны, то вывести только title, а если не равны и то и другое.

[image: схема таблицы из базы]

Это схема таблицы из базы, формируется такой же массив уже в php.

```
$sql = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($sql);
if ($sql['title'] == $sql['original_title']) {

    do{
        echo "<div class='search_result'>".$sql['title']."</div>";
    }while($sql = $query->fetch());
#code...
} else {
    do{
        echo "<div class='search_result'>".$sql['title']." (".$sql['original_title'].")</div>";
    }while($sql = $query->fetch());
}
```

sql запрос:

```
SELECT movie_id, title, original_title, poster_path, release_date
  FROM movie
 WHERE (original_title LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
    OR (title LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
```

Comment: //случайно отправил раньше времени. Почему-то сравнение $sql['title'] == $sql['original_title'] выдает неверный результат, отправляет в else при одинаковых значениях title и original_title

Comment: напишите ваш `sql` запрос в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется понял что не так, извините запрос не надо было.
Как я понял вам нужно сделать вот так:

```
do{
    if($sql['title'] == $sql['original_title']){
        echo "<div class='search_result'>".$sql['title']."</div>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class='search_result'>".$sql['title']." (".$sql['original_title'].")</div>";
    }

}while($sql = $query->fetch());
```

Если в чем то не прав скажите. Но как я понял вот эта строка не должно было работать у вас верно?

```
if ($sql['title'] == $sql['original_title'])
```

Вы сравниваете какие то переменные до добавления в них какого то значения по итерации.

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы, спасибо большое, никак не мог догадаться. А, казалось бы, такая простая вещь.

Comment: @Osigot Иногда такие простые вещи очень трудно заметить. спасибо за птичку.